# Python NxN matrix is not setting None values correctly

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

I have the following code in Python 3:

```
def matrix(n:int) -> list:
    matrix = list([[None]*n]*n)

    count = 1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            print(i, j, count)
            matrix[i][j] = count
            count += 1

    return matrix

number = 3
print(matrix(number))
```

Below is the `print` result:

```
    0 0 1
    0 1 2
    0 2 3
    1 0 4
    1 1 5
    1 2 6
    2 0 7
    2 1 8
    2 2 9
    [[7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
```

As you see, indexes are correct, but it does not return the expected value of `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`. There has to be a fundamental reason for this behavior, and of course, by using other methods, such as `append()`, the result is correct.

Comment: `matrix = [[None]*n for i in range(n)]` This gives you separate 3 list which combinedly forms the main list.

Comment: Hi, i added oneline function that answer, check my update :)

Answer (score 1):

`matrix = list([[None]*n]*n)` can makes some problems, you can read more about it in [here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html)

I would do it as:

```py
def matrix(n:int) -> list:
     matrix = []
     count = 1
     for i in range(n):
         matrix.append([])
         for j in range(n):
             matrix[i].append(count)
             count+=1

     return matrix

number = 3
print(matrix(number))
```

to avoid problems with mutable objects

## Update

If you want a oneliner:

```
def g(n):
     return [list(range(i+i+1, i+n+i+1)) for i in range(0,n*2, 2)]
```